# Ignore accents in solr and sunspot

Tags: search, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-rails

If I search for "agua" no result as ignoring the accents (á, ã, ç) in search?

**#city data base (id, name, uf, province_id)**
   `1 Águas Clara PR 3
    2 águas       PR 4
    3 Áraguaia    PR 3`

**#schema.xml**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory in your filter chain, for both index and query. Using your example:

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: If you need to configure this in Heroku (using Websolr), be sure to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382962/solr-configuration-on-heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run an analysis to see what is happening when querying vs when indexing.

Try something like that, adjusting for the host, core and field names:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue=%C3%A1guas&analysis.query=%C3%A1guas&analysis.fieldname=name
```

The result will show how your query terms are handled at all the steps of the analysis

```
{
   responseHeader:{
      status:0,
      QTime:2
   },
   analysis:{
      field_types:{

      },
      field_names:{
         Noms:{
            index:[
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer",
               [
                  {
                     text:"état",
                     raw_bytes:"[c3 a9 74 61 74]",
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>",
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.ASCIIFoldingFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     match:true,
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>"
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     match:true,
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>"
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     match:true,
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1,
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>"
                  }
               ]
            ],
            query:[
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer",
               [
                  {
                     text:"état",
                     raw_bytes:"[c3 a9 74 61 74]",
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>",
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.ASCIIFoldingFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>"
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength:1,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>",
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1,
                        1
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1,
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>",
                     org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength:1
                  }
               ],
               "org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter",
               [
                  {
                     text:"etat",
                     raw_bytes:"[65 74 61 74]",
                     position:1,
                     positionHistory:[
                        1,
                        1,
                        1,
                        1,
                        1
                     ],
                     start:0,
                     end:4,
                     type:"<ALPHANUM>",
                     org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength:1
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```